# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Blue color' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, types

2

Hi! I am trying to create stored procedure that gone return varchar value, and that value I need to display in textbox.

This is the code for stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE Status @id_doc int, @Name varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
select  @Name =items.name    
from Doc,Items where @id_doc=IDN and doc.IDN=Items.ID 
return @Name
```

This is the code in vb.net where i need to display returned value from procedure in textbox:

```
Public Sub Current()
    Dim dtc As New Data.DataTable
    Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim id_doc As Integer
    Dim dset As New DataSet
    Dim recordset As DataRow
    Dim Name As String

    Try
        id_doc = idDocExplorer
        cmd.Connection = pubCon
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "Status"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_doc", id_doc)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
        cmd.Parameters("@Name ").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        Name = cmd.Parameters("@Name").Value
       TextBox1.text=Name
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        dtc = Nothing
        dr = Nothing
        da = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I try to execute this code I get this message in exception:

"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Blue color' to data type int."

What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Serkan: It is vb.net (and it is tagged so).

Comment: was tagged as a C# too, anyway its fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RETURN takes an integer argument only so `return @Name` is causing it

Use this instead to return a record set (with a proper JOIN too)

```
select
    items.name    
from
    Doc
    JOIN
    Items ON doc.IDN = Items.ID 
where
    @id_doc = IDN
```

Although, it can be written like this too because `@id_doc = doc.IDN = Items.ID`:

```
select
    items.name    
from
    Items
where
    Items.ID = @id_doc
```

If you want to use an OUTPUT parameter rather than a recordset, then simply remove the RETURN statement and leave the assign to @Name

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Status @id_doc int, @Name varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
select @Name = items.name from Items where Items.ID = @id_doc
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are passing "Blue Color" as a parameter value under `id_doc`.
And the stored procedure call could be failing because it accepts an `int` type as 1st input parameter

Comment: no, OP is trying to return "blue colour" via the return statement

Comment: @gbn: What happens if you pas a varchar value for an int parameter?

Comment: @gbn: Was the sight of `RETURN` statement reason for your answer? For me, I didn't know what user could be passing for `id_doc`.

Comment: The vb.net has `Dim id_doc As Integer` so you can't pass "blue colour" to SQL; it would fail earlier. But the error message is a SQL error, not .net, so it must be in the SQL code. I did not jump on RETURN immediately, I worked through and analyzed the problem...

Comment: @gbn: Hmmm. I jumped onto error message & thought it is SQL error. And hence, there must be something wrong in .net code (string value passed instead of int). Thanks for your reply. It helps me understand that I should analyze things in detail & not rush to answer :)